# Why constructor of two root service does not work?

Tags: angular

Here is two root services:

**Service 1:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  private data$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  public dataObs$ = this.data$.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  setData(data: any) {
    this.data$.next(data);
  }

  loadData(url: string, category: number) {
    return this.http.get(`${url}?chapter=${category}`);
  }
}
```

**Service 2:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ImportExportService {
  private data$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.data$ = this.dataService.dataObs$;
    this.data$.subscribe((e) => console.log(e));
    alert('Done');
  }
}
```

Why constructor of the second service does not work, I dont get message `alert('Done');`.

Both are registered as root service

Comment: Do you Inject `ImportExportService ` somewhere in your components?

Comment: No. I checked, only in root

Comment: I think Angular creates an instance of the service only if you inject it in some component constructor

Comment: It is a good assumption, I will check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular create an instance of service only if it's injected somewhere in your components ( or other classes such as guards, pipes, etc ) .
if you didn't inject it in any constructor, no insatnce of that service will be created.
for more see [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#dependency-injection-di)